# Jenkins host running out of disk space

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

Am running Jenkins on GCP in a VM. After some runs, I get an error stating "***no space left on device***". I have deleted all contents of the **/var/lib/workspace** directory. but I still get the same error. am having this Jenkins to build docker images for deployment to GKE. I have also deleted all docker images and Docker containers but still same error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? What does the command "df -h" gives you? How often do you build your images? Do you put them in a gcp docker repo after build and do you delete them after the build is finished?

Answer (score 3):

It may happen if some large file has been deleted, but is still opened by some process. Check with the command `lsof | grep deleted` to see which processes have opened descriptors to deleted files. 
You can restart the process and the space will be freed.

Another ting is to prune the docker

The most useful command to free space on the Docker side is as below:

```
docker system prune
```

This will remove:

- all stopped containers
- all volumes not used by at least one container
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all dangling images

To clean your system, first remove containers

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

then remove images

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

This will remove all containers and all images. You can remove them one at at time via `docker rm #CONTAINER_ID#` and `docker rmi #IMAGE_ID`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the /temp or the jenkins installation directory.

try the command "df -sh" and check the disk availability.

> ```
>  [root@localhost ~]# df -h
>    Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>    /dev/mapper/centos-root  200G  2.0G  198G   1% /
>    devtmpfs                 5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
>    tmpfs                    5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev/shm
>    tmpfs                    5.8G   33M  5.8G   1% /run
>    tmpfs                    5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>    /dev/sda1               1014M  129M  886M  13% /boot
>    tmpfs                    1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/0
>    /dev/dm-3                 10G  238M  9.8G   3%
> ```

You can find the root cause.

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 says: `df: invalid option -- 's'`